# How do I enable builder like pattern for multiple interface inheritance?

Tags: java, builder

First, lets define our interfaces:

```java
public interface Transformable<T> {
    <R extends Transformable<T>> R registerTransformation(Function<T,T> transformation);
    T process(T entity);
}
```

```java
public interface HttpService<T> {
    T execute(URL url);
}
```

As seen in interface `Transformable<T>`, we can create a simple builder pattern to register transformations and execute all of them in a single line, e.g :

```java
new DefaultTransformableImpl<Integer>(){}
    .registerTransformation(number -> number * 2)
    .registerTransformation(number -> number - 1)
    .registerTransformation(number -> number * number)
    .process(109845)
```

Ok, now we're ready to create our implementation of `HttpService`. The idea of this is to give the possibility to modify the headers, HTTP method... of the connection instance before actually sending the request to the server and without needing to specify method adapters for the `org.jsoup.Connection` interface:

```java
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.List;
import java.net.URL;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

public class JsoupHttpService implements HttpService<Document>, Transformable<Connection> {
    private final List<Function<Connection, Connection>> fns = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override public <R extends Transformable<Connection>> R registerTransformation(Function<Connection, Connection> transformation) {
        this.fns.add(transformation);
        return (R) this;
    }

    @Override public Connection process(Connection connection) {
        return fns.stream().reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen).apply(connection);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override public Document execute(URL url) {
        return this.process(HttpConnection.connect(url)).execute().parse();
    }
}
```

This is just a simplification of the actual implementation focusing only the necessary parts of the problem, which can be seen by trying to use `JsoupHttpService` with method chaining:

```java
public Document doSomething() {
    return new JsoupHttpService(){}
        .registerTransformation(connection -> connection.method(Connection.Method.GET))
        .registerTransformation(connection -> connection.userAgent("fake user-agent"))
        .execute("https://www.google.com")
        .parse();
}
```

If you try this in your IDE, it will say something close to *Cannot resolve method 'execute' in 'Transformable'*... so I wonder if you guys know how could I fix this problem without modifying both interfaces.
is my only option to create another interface extending `HttpService` and trying to adapt the methods defined in `Transformable` inside it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `registerTransformation` returns a `Transformable`. A `Transformable` is not an `HttpService`.

You can achieve what you want with this:

```
JsoupHttpService service = new JsoupHttpService();
service.registerTransformation(connection -> connection.method(Connection.Method.GET));
service.registerTransformation(connection -> connection.userAgent("fake user-agent"));
service.execute();
```

Seems the author of the Transformable interface does not properly understand when it is appropriate to use `extends`. The unchecked cast to `(R)` should be a clue to that.

Comment: You're right, but that doesn't help with the method chaining thing. And yes, the unsafe cast if kinda annoying... how could I solve it? I fell like extends is necessary in order to be able to use the interface implementations concrete methods and attributes.

Comment: You asked how to solve it without changing those interfaces. This is how. It works - why are you so concerned about whether you can chain them or not?

Comment: I understand your concerns... it enables using other interesting patterns.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest almost any use of multiple inheritance, even of interface, is a bad idea. Also, mixing generics with inheritance of type leads to nightmarish messes - look at the weird constructions revolving around `Comparable` and `Enum`.

Obviously that isn't going to stop me fixing code.

If you have a method with a type parameter that is only used for a return type, the options for the method are: return `null`, throw an exception, perform heap type pollution, not bother to return or worse.

The solution with these sort of problems with builders is to messily parameterise the builder type with a recursively defined type parameter and possibly add an abstract "get this" method (more common if the `Transformable` was abstract and so could have fields.

```
public interface Transformable<THIS extends Transformable<THIS, T>, T> {
    THIS registerTransformation(Function<T, T> transformation);
    T process(T entity);
}

public class JsoupHttpService implements HttpService<Document>, Transformable<Connection> {
    private final List<Function<Connection, Connection>> fns = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override public JsoupHttpService registerTransformation(Function<Connection, Connection> transformation) {
        this.fns.add(transformation);
        return this;
    }
```

For the "get this" suppose `Transformable` had a common default implementation method

```
    // Silly example.
    default THIS setSomethingWhichUsuallyHasNoEffect() {
        // In an abstract class, could assign fields here.
        return getThis(); // Cannot inline within source.
    }
    abstract THIS getThis(); // Would be protects in abstract class.
```

Then in `JsoupHttpService`:

```
    @Override public JsoupHttpService getThis() {
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Indeed it's a bit messy but I've tried it and it surprisingly works. Thank you! (I'm not sure about the need of the `getThis()` method)